# Default value is not set as prefilled

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, xsd

I have the sample of paymentcard tag as listed below in my xsd:

```
<xs:element name="paymentCard" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="cardsTypeRestriction" name="cardType" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="cardHolderName" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="validFrom" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="expirationDate" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="cardNumbers" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="cardNumber" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="cardCurrencies" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element type="cardsCurrencyRestriction" name="cardCurrency" maxOccurs="unbounded" default="GBP"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="cardAmounts" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element type="xs:float" name="cardAmount" maxOccurs="unbounded" default="20.00"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="cardCvv" maxOccurs="1" default="123"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="cardIssueNumber" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

But when I create xml from such xsd, it does not provide me any default prefilled value, so i get this xml:

```
<paymentCard>
    <cardType></cardType>
    <cardNumbers>
         <cardNumber></cardNumber>
    </cardNumbers>
    <cardCurrencies>
         <cardCurrency></cardCurrency>
    </cardCurrencies>
    <cardAmounts>
         <cardAmount></cardAmount>
    </cardAmounts>
    <cardCvv></cardCvv>
</paymentCard>
```

What I want to get when creating new xml is

```
<paymentCard>
    <cardType></cardType>
    <cardNumbers>
         <cardNumber></cardNumber>
    </cardNumbers>
    <cardCurrencies>
         <cardCurrency>GBP</cardCurrency>
    </cardCurrencies>
    <cardAmounts>
         <cardAmount>20.00</cardAmount>
    </cardAmounts>
    <cardCvv>123</cardCvv>
</paymentCard>
```

to fill cardType and cardNumber only.
Is that possible? If yes, what is wrong in my xsd?

Comment: How – what tool – are you using to generate the XML?

Comment: I'm working with Intellij IDEA v13.1 comm. edition